# Search query to find all of my answers which has the string (*SKIP)(*F)

Tags: support, search

I want to find all of my answers which has the string `(*SKIP)(*F)`. I need to look at my previous answers which has the string mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the search box, use `user:me "(*SKIP)(*F)"`.

This would result in the following search URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3297613+%22%28*SKIP%29%28*F%29%22
```

Optionally add `is:a` in the search query to filter on answers only.